# I'm confused about declaring and using characters - for instance in this sscanf example

Tags: c++, char, scanf

The following example works fine:

```
char rc[20]="1,150";
char command[1];
int data1 = 0;
int data2 = 0;
int data3 = 0;
int count = sscanf(rc, "%c,%d,%d,%d", command, &data1, &data2, &data3);
```

It gives:
 count = 2; command[0] = 1; data1 = 150

But I don't know how to make this work if command is defined as:
`char command;` or `char * command`.

Comment: In this case `command` decays to a pointer to its first element and is equivalent to `&command[0]`.

Comment: Instead of declaring an array of 1, you could use a `char` variable.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you are expecting to happen. Are you expecting command to be '1'? If so, what is supposed to happen to the comma? Is the result you get not what you're expecting?

Comment: Yes, the result is as I expect (sscanf uses the comma in the format string to delimit the parameters and ignores the comma ... I could just as well have used a ' ' or any other non-alpha character).  My question (which has been answered) had to do with using sscanf to copy the first character to the command character, without having to define command as a char[].

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
char command;
```

then you can use the address-of operator `&`:

```
sscanf(..., &command, ...);
```

---

If you have

```
char *command;
```

then you first need to make the pointer point somewhere valid:

```
command = malloc(1);
```

or

```
char actual_command;
command = &actual_command;
```

then use `command` like you do in your question.

---

All of this should be in your text-book or taught in class. If not, then change book or class (or pay more attention in class, if you missed it).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to make this work if command is defined as: char
>   command; or char * command.

You always need to make sure that `sscanf` is passed *the address of the character* you want to store the value in. (Originally you passed in `command`, which is the name of an array of `char`, which is equivalent to the address of the first member in the array. (The only member, since "you" declared an array size of 1.))

In the first case, your code is almost correct as-is.

```
char command;
int count = sscanf(rc, "%c,%d,%d,%d", &command, &data1, &data2, &data3);
```

The second case is trickier. It's easy to pass the address of a character, because `command` would be exactly that type. But what is the pointer pointing at? You need to initialize its value so that it points at a `char` which you can write to.

```
char comm_value = '?';
char* command = &comm_value;
int count = sscanf(rc, "%c,%d,%d,%d", command, &data1, &data2, &data3);
```

Comment: Many thanks. I did try the first example (char command; &command) but for some reason the compiler threw up an error saying that the command parameter was of type int instead of char*. But I've tried it again and it works. I missed the char* command requiring allocation of a character!